# Nuget crash in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Nuget crash while building in VS 2012 (update 5) with the following details:

Will appreciate any info about this issue.
Nuget version 2.8.60318.667

**VS2012 Error report:**

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01:   NuGet.exe

Problem Signature 02:   4.6.2.5055

Problem Signature 03:   5abc2994

Problem Signature 04:   NuGet

Problem Signature 05:   4.6.2.5055

Problem Signature 06:   5abc2994

Problem Signature 07:   113a

Problem Signature 08:   1d

Problem Signature 09:   System.MissingMethodException

OS Version: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.4

Locale ID:  1033

Additional Information 1:   b7d6

Additional Information 2:   b7d6c2e5daaa8871798cc10ddd35970b

Additional Information 3:   5b5d

Additional Information 4:   5b5d296921c7f5f427d03f948377754e
```

**Error description:**

> Error 60  The command "".nuget\NuGet.exe" install
>   "\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive
>   -RequireConsent -solutionDir " "" exited with code -532462766.

**In output tab:**

> 1>.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Unhandled Exception:
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[]
>   System.Array.Empty()'.
>
> 1>.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error :    at
>   NuGet.Common.CommandLineResponseFile.ParseArgsResponseFiles(String[]
>   args, Int32 parseArgsResponseFileRecursionDepth)
>
> 1>.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error :    at
>   NuGet.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> 1>.nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error MSB3073: The command
>   "".nuget\NuGet.exe" install "\packages.config" -source "" 
>   -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "\ "" exited with code -532462766. 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by downgrading from Nuget 4.6.2 to Nuget 4.1.0. Not sure why problem occurred in the first place.